# Set Default Zoom in Flutter Web to 150%

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web, flutter-web

Is there anyway to set the default zoom of a flutter web app to 150% by default?

I tried Viewport and tried to edit the Index.html file but it didn't work because Flutter overrides those already.